# Is the essentia library implemented in C++ slower than the librosa library implemented in Python?

Tags: python, c++, audio

Essentia is a python library for audio and music analysis, developed in C++ with a Python wrapper.
In theory, essentia developed in C++ should be faster than pure-Python implementation of librosa, but, I am going to extract a large amount of mel feature data. I just saw
https://github.com/libAudioFlux/audioFlux/issues/22

After running the test demo, I found that essentia is slower than audioflux and librosa when extracting long audio. (Note: Audioflux is an audio library developed in C and wrapped in Python)

[This is performance comparison data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACyHH.png)

Then I used the method of extracting mel in the document and found that it was still very slow. Is it because I used something wrong?

Here is my way of using it:

```py
import time
import numpy as np
import essentia
import essentia.standard as es
import librosa
import audioflux as af

frameSize = 2048
hopSize = 512
sample_rate = 32000
data_len = frameSize + hopSize * 999

windowing = es.Windowing(type='blackmanharris62', zeroPadding=0)
spectrum = es.Spectrum(size=frameSize)
melbands = es.MelBands(inputSize=frameSize // 2 + 1, sampleRate=sample_rate,    numberBands=128,type='power',lowFrequencyBound=0, highFrequencyBound=16000, warpingFormula='slaneyMel')

use_time = 0
for _ in range(10):
    audio = np.random.randn(data_len).astype(np.float32)
    pool = essentia.Pool()
    s = time.time()
    for frame in es.FrameGenerator(audio, frameSize=frameSize, hopSize=hopSize,  startFromZero=True, lastFrameToEndOfFile=False):
        frame_spectrum = spectrum(windowing(frame))
        frame_mel = melbands(frame_spectrum)
        pool.add('mel128', frame_mel)
    mel128 = np.array(pool['mel128'])
    use_time += time.time() - s
    # print(mel128.shape)
print('essentia use time:', use_time)
```

essentia use time: 0.5148606300354004

Comment: Any question concerning the speed of a C++ program must be accompanied by the compiler and compiler settings, mostly the optimization settings, that were used to build the application.  If you are timing a "debug" or an unoptimized build, the timings are meaningless.

Comment: I haven't dealt with the C/C++ compilation level yet, I'm using the official release version of essentia.  However, the audioflux library, which is also implemented in C, is much faster than essentia and librosa. Surprisingly, the C++ implementation of essentia is the slowest, so this result is very confusing

Comment: What are the results of your benchmarking?  Did you search for performance / benchmarking results of the library?  Remember, the more iterations you measure, the better your average result will be.

Comment: Being written in C++ doesn't guarantee a given library will be faster than another. It's not difficult to implement slow algorithms and data structures using C++. Also note that the librosa library uses NumPy and SciPy for numeric functions so I wouldn't call it "pure" Python.